# MVC Ajax Form returning entire contents of View

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC4.  Unobtrusive JavaScript is enabled and referenced in my project.  The Ajax scripts are loading in my shared master page.  FireBug reports no errors or 404's.

I have added a `Text` box to my page, which updates the contents of a `Hidden` field inside of my `Ajax` form.  When a user presses a key, and the `KeyUp` event fires, I force my `Ajax` form to submit by calling:

```
$("form#ajaxForm").trigger("submit");
```

Where *ajaxForm* is the name of the Ajax form.  This works fine.  The form is submitted, behind the scenes, and my controller event fires.  The Model is updated with the new data, based on the input from the user.

However, where it gets strange, is when the result returns to my form.  The entire contents of my form `div` tag is replaced by the result -- which is the entire page.

```
<div id="basic-modal-content"">
   <input id="breed" type="text"/>
<div>
<form id="ajaxForm" method="post" data-ajax-update="#results" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax="true" action="/Poultry/ListBreeds?Length=7">
   <div id="results">
    ->THIS AREA IS GETTING REPLACED WITH THE ENTIRE FORM <-
      <div id="basic-modal-content">
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

- Notice how *basic-modal-content* now contains itself, another *basic-modal-content*.  The result div should only contain the updates results, not the entire view -- obviously.

My code is as follows:

**View** (*BreedSelectorPartial.cshtml*)

```
@model IQueryable<Inert.BreedViewModel>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#breed").keyup(function (e) {
            $("input[name=breedSearch]").val($("#breed").val());
            $("form#ajaxForm").trigger("submit");
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="basic-modal-content">
<input id="breed" type="text" style="width:100%; height:22px;" />
    <div>
        <div style="margin-top: 4px;">
            <label for="breed">Begin by typing a breed, e.g. <span style="font-style: italic">Wyandotte</span></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ListBreeds", "Poultry", new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId = "results" }, new { id = "ajaxForm" }))
    {
        <input id="breedSearch" name="breedSearch" type="hidden" />
    }
    <div id="results" style="height: 320px; color: black; margin-top: 12px; font-size: 18px;">
        @{
            var grid = new WebGrid(Model, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "results");
            int c = Model.Count();
         }
        @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webgrid",
            alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
            rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
            displayHeader: true)
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.simplemodal.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/basic.js"></script>
```

**Controller** (*PoultryController.cs*)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ListBreeds(string breedSearch)
{
    InertDatabaseEntitiesConnection db = new InertDatabaseEntitiesConnection();
    var breeds = db.Breeds.Where(q => q.Name.Contains(breedSearch));
    var names = breeds.Select(q => new BreedViewModel { Name = q.Name });
    return PartialView("BreedSelectorPartial", names);
}
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong on this.  I've spent hours trying to figure this out.  Any solutions?

Comment: its because of your view model display template... your returning object matching to your main view model @model IQueryable<Inert.BreedViewModel>... so its direcly calling that view

Comment: Could you show the contents of your `BreedSelectorPartial.cshtml` partial?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov The markup code above is the `BreedSelectorPartial.cshtml` view. What I'm attempting to do, is to get the view to call itself to get an updated Model -- but only replace the area in the *results* div with the changes.

Comment: OK, I thought that was your main view. Didn't read your question carefully. Now it's all clear. See my answer. The `#results` div must be outside the partial in the main view.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first issue is that you are using a wrong overload of the `Ajax.BeginForm` helper (but that's not causing the undesired behavior, it's just a sidenote):

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    "ListBreeds",                                      // actionName
    "Poultry",                                         // routeValues
    new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "results" },    // ajaxOptions
    new { id = "ajaxForm" })                           // htmlAttributes
)
```

whereas you need:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    "ListBreeds",                                      // actionName
    "Poultry",                                         // controllerName
    null,                                              // routeValues
    new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "results" },    // ajaxOptions
    new { id = "ajaxForm" })                           // htmlAttributes
)
```

---

Now the real issue is that you need to put the `#results` div **outside** the partial and inside your main view:

```
<div id="results" style="height: 320px; color: black; margin-top: 12px; font-size: 18px;">
    @Html.Partial("BreedSelectorPartial")
</div>
```

Now of course if you only need to update the `WebGrid` portion then it would make more sense to leave only the grid inside the partial and move the form outside in the main view.

So your main view now becomes:

```
@model IQueryable<BreedViewModel>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#breed").keyup(function (e) {
            $("input[name=breedSearch]").val($("#breed").val());
            $("form#ajaxForm").trigger("submit");
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="basic-modal-content">
    <input id="breed" type="text" style="width:100%; height:22px;" />
    <div>
        <div style="margin-top: 4px;">
            <label for="breed">Begin by typing a breed, e.g. <span style="font-style: italic">Wyandotte</span></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ListBreeds", "Poultry", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "results" }, new { id = "ajaxForm" }))
    {
        <input id="breedSearch" name="breedSearch" type="hidden" />
    }
    <div id="results" style="height: 320px; color: black; margin-top: 12px; font-size: 18px;">
        @Html.Partial("BreedSelectorPartial")
    </div>
</div>
```

and the only portion that needs to be updated is the `BreedSelectorPartial.cshtml` partial which contains the grid:

```
@model IQueryable<BreedViewModel>
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "results");
}
@grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "webgrid",
    alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
    rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
    displayHeader: true
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar to this the other day.

I cannot remember what the exact problem was but it was something to do with returning the whole object and not just the HTML element of the object.

I cannot find the code at the moment, but if you are using Firebug or something similar, see if you can put a watch on the data that's returned and if i rememeber correctly all i needed to do was add .html to the end of the line.

Sorry its a  bit vague, but hopefully it will help you a bit.

Comment: I am doing that -- it's replacing the entire contents of the *results* div with the form.  That's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not doing the regular form submit ? I think this line  `$("form#ajaxForm").trigger("submit");`
is doing the regular form submit. You should probably do an ajax form post here instead of invoking the normal form submit. You are seeing the entire page reload because of that.

Comment: The entire page isn't reloading. The contents of the result div is being reloaded with the entire contents of the partial view.